# How to call the Base class constructor in multi-level Inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have this code and i want to call the move method of the `Shape` class in the `Childbox` class

```
class Shape {
    move() {
        console.log('move.');
    }
}

class Box extends Shape {
    move() {
        console.log('Box move.')
    }
}

class Childbox extends Box {
    move() {
        super.move();
        console.log('Childbox move.')
    }
}
```

> I use `super.move()` it gives the box `move()` , so how to call the
> Shape class `move()` in the `Childbox`

Comment: You don't want to make Box#move() call super.move() too?

Comment: yes i dont. @sp00m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always call arbitrary methods on your instances with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), including the `move` prototype method of the `Shape` class:

```
class Childbox extends Box {
    move() {
        Shape.prototype.move.call(this);
        console.log('Childbox move.')
    }
}
```

<sub>(In fact that's the traditional way to do super method calls, before ES6 introduced the `super` keyword.)</sub>

However, when you find yourself looking for something like this, I'd consider that a smell that your multi-level inheritance hierarchy is dodgy. Consider using a different design.