# How can I call same-level method in base class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

This is the code I have

```
class Parent {
  async A(part, id) {
  }

  async B(part, id) {
    await this.A(part, id)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  async A(id) {
  }

  async B(id) {
    await super.B("part1", id);
    // ...
  }
}

// let's assume I'm in async context
const child = new Child();
await child.B();
```

So what is happening here is the Child.B is calling Parent.B, and Parent.B is calling Child.A (which is expected).

I want to know if there is a way for me to call Parent.B > Parent.A.

I realize that perhaps I need to rename the methods, but I wanted to know if there is a way for this.

Comment: you certainly can call `super.A`...

Comment: @DanielA.White No, that won't work. `Parent.A` has no `super`.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060621/prototype-chain-call-super-method-over-multiple-levels/25060720#25060720) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879135/js-why-would-child-class-method-call-parent-class-method)

Comment: Another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62681646/how-to-call-the-base-class-constructor-in-multi-level-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a method of a specific class instead of looking it up on the instance (on `this`) or your own prototype ([trough `super`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64395149/1048572)), reference that method directly and [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) it on the instance:

```
class Parent {
  async A(part, id) {
  }

  async B(part, id) {
    await Parent.prototype.A.call(this, part, id)
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, this definitely worked, thanks!